# Codeigniter - issue in setting flashdata

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

This is my code in a method:

```
public function index() {
    $pathToFile = $this->session->flashdata( 'img_path' );
    if ( $pathToFile ) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata( 'file' , $pathToFile );
        $this->session->set_flashdata( 'img_path' , $pathToFile );

        $data[ 'pageTitle' ] = BLOGER_TITLE . ' دانلود تصاویر';
        $data[ 'is_logedin' ] = $this->is_logedin();
        $data[ 'banners' ] = $this->_getBanners( 'side' );
        $data[ 'img_name' ] = basename( $pathToFile );
        $this->load->view( 'download_image' , $data );
    } else {
        show_404();
    }
}
```

Lets say user can't access this method unless having visited another method and setting the flashdata named `img_path` there, and then redirect to this method.
so far this method works perfect as expected, but if the user make a refresh on the page ,error 404 page should appear. I want to keep the flashdata alive while user is refreshing current page so I should add a `$this->session->keep_flashdata('img_path');` in index method (or constructor, I tried both) to do so, or i should add another `$this->session->set_flashdata('img_path',$pathToFile);` but both solution does't work for me. Why?
for testing I put a `var_dump($this->session->flashdata('img_path'));` in the end of method . after redirect to this method I have the img_path but after refresh it doesn't the value so I tried setting the flashdata I in the method  and I will have it and after refreshing the page it will set to null. and also the other flashdata named `file` never get the value assigned to it. why is this happening?

my session config is as bellow and I loaded the session library in `autoload.php` and it works fine in other controllers and pages.

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

**-------------------------------------**

**UPDATE**

**-------------------------------------**

A little simplicity in code:

```
public function test1() {
    $this->session->set_flashdata( 'img_path',"abc" );
    redirect('imgs/test2','refresh');
}

public function test2() {

    $this->session->keep_flashdata( 'img_path' );
    $pathToFile = $this->session->flashdata( 'img_path' );
    if ( $pathToFile ) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata( 'file' , $pathToFile );
        $this->session->set_flashdata( 'img_path' , $pathToFile );

        var_dump($pathToFile);
    } else {
        show_404();
    }
}
```

When I go to `localhost/imgs/test1` a it will set the flashdata and redirect me to `localhost/imgs/test2` and the `var_dump(...)` section will run and prints "abc" for me in details.
but when refreshing the page its show me `404 error page` because the flashdata is not exists anymore, even when I used `keep_flashdata`.

Comment: You're using flashdata in a manner its not really intended for. Why not just set it in your session then unset it when you're done?

Comment: i want the session destroyed if user change controller. i thought this is the best approach without any extra coding in other controllers constructor in order to delete the session if exists?

Answer (score 0):

It should work with keep_flash data. Example:

```
    public function test() {
      //From this request session will be set
        $this->session->set_flashdata( 'img_path',"abc" );
        redirect(base_url()."home/test");
    }

    public function index() {
    $this->session->keep_flashdata('img_path');
    $pathToFile = $this->session->flashdata( 'img_path' );
    if ( $pathToFile ) {
         $this->session->set_flashdata( 'file' , $pathToFile );
         $this->session->set_flashdata( 'img_path' , $pathToFile );

         $data[ 'pageTitle' ] = BLOGER_TITLE . ' دانلود تصاویر';
         $data[ 'is_logedin' ] = $this->is_logedin();
         $data[ 'banners' ] = $this->_getBanners( 'side' );
         $data[ 'img_name' ] = basename( $pathToFile );
         $this->load->view( 'download_image' , $data );
    } else {
        show_404();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for quick answer, but in the test() function i should redirect to same method or i should redirect to index method?

Comment: its not working. is there any config i should set? its like after refresh the flashdata is cleared. but before refresh i have the value

Comment: if you are using `$this->session->keep_flashdata('img_path');` then flash data will not erase. double check your code. And also check if you are not distroy session data.

Comment: I used a simple approach and updated the question. the code is logically correct but still no results and keep_flashdata() is not working. please help...